# GitLab CI - Trigger the job based on pattern match in the rules from dotenv variables of an other job

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, dotenv

I have two jobs in the Gitlab CI file.

1. First job **env_var_test** generates the dotenv variables from the command.

   `echo '{"apple":red,"boy":"bar","cat":"white"}' | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]'`
2. Second job **env_var_retrive_test** looks for a variable from **env_var_test** dotenv variables and if the variable match the predefined value of the CICD rules, it triggers

```
env_var_test:
  stage: build
  image: $CFIMAGE
  script:
    - echo '{"apple":red,"boy":"bar","cat":"white"}' | jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' > deploy.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env
  tags:
    - linux

env_var_retrive_test:
  stage: deploy
  image: $CFIMAGE
  script:
    - echo "[ $apple - $boy - $cat ]"
  tags:
    - linux
  rules:
    - if: '$boy == "bar"'
      when: always
```

With this setup, I tested them and could see the variables are correctly printing `echo "[ $apple - $boy - $cat ]"`. However, the job was not triggering if I defined the variables in the rules section

```
  rules:
    - if: '$boy == "bar"'
      when: always
```

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong or help me with any better approach to do the same.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

> You cannot use dotenv variables created in job scripts in rules, because rules are evaluated before any jobs run.

Feature request: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/235812. Please vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing Variable to some value, you should not enclose in quotes. You should use `- if $boy == "bar"`

Comment: `
    - if: $boy == "bar"
`
This one didn't work. 
 
` 
    - if: $boy =~ 'bar'
`

matched everything even though it's the wrong match.

Comment: sorry but the feature itself is not available currently in GitLab